# selecting random table from database

Tags: php, mysql, rss

This is my rss.php file for rss feed the problem I encounter is that - I can select only one table from database at a time,I know about joins but I don't have anything in common,moreover I want that it should select random table from database and then fetch its respective title,content and summary,Is there some way to do that,just like we can use rand() function (order by rand()) something like this,so that I can get random table from database in select * query.So that I can have mixed rss feeds from all the tables.

```
 <?php


    function connect() {
        return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jossicoa_writeups', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    }

    $pdo = connect();


    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM scienceandtechnology';
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $rs_post = $query->fetchAll();

    // The XML structure
    $data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
    $data .= '<rss version="2.0">';
    $data .= '<channel>';
    $data .= '<title>Jossips</title>';
    $data .= '<link>http://www.google.com</link>';
    $data .= '<description>various section</description>';
    foreach ($rs_post as $row) {
        $data .= '<item>';
        $data .= '<title>'.$row['title'].'</title>';
        $data .= '<link>'.$row['content'].'</link>';
        $data .= '<description>'.$row['summary'].'</description>';
        $data .= '</item>';
    }
    $data .= '</channel>';
    $data .= '</rss> ';

    header('Content-Type: application/xml');
    echo $data;
    ?>
```

Comment: I don't think you want a random table from the entire database. I think you will make problems for yourself that way. What about defining a list of tables in php and then picking one at random and adding it to the query?

Comment: yes that could be done@xdhmoore

Comment: could you please give a basic idea how to do that@Drew

Comment: could you tell how that would be done@xdhmoore

Comment: $a=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
    select * from   (array_rand($a,1) is this what you are saying?@xdhmoore

Comment: Yeah, something like that. I don't know PHP though, so I can't really help you there.  You might try that and then update your answer with a specific error message if it doesn't work.  Folks here like specific questions.

Comment: `array_rand` returns the key, not the value of the key. So in your case you would return a, b, c, or d not red, green, blue, or yellow. Getting the value of the key takes a bit more code.

Comment: please tell how that would be done@Kuya

Comment: $a=array("a"=>"post","b"=>"content");
$t=print_r(array_rand($a,1));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$t.""; iam getting an error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1' in E:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\h\rss.php:12 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\h\rss.php(12): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\h\rss.php on line 12@xdhmoore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
$myarray = array('tbl1','tbl2','tbl3','tbl4');
// get random value from array
$key = array_rand($myarray);
$table= $myarray[$key];
```

Then you can run your sql query...

```
select * from $table ...
```

Comment: Better yet, select the table names from the information_schema for your database

Comment: @John Not, necessarily. I'm sure there are other tables that the OP would want to exclude from the list such as an administrators table for logins, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be instead to create a separate table for categories, and use a foreign key into that table from a single table containing all your content. That way you can easily select a random row from the categories table, and use that to select rows from your content table.